# what is the best design for the table which have one forign key and the FK has multiple tags and every tags has its own table table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

hey i just want to create a table for photo .which has a column that  can store multiple type like it belongs to the (wildlife, nature ,adventure..etc) and the tags liks with its own table for the table updation record

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead keeping 6 columns.

photo_tag_id, photo_tag, photo_links, photo_created_date, photo_updated_date

This table would be unique on photo_tag_id and photo_tag  primary indexed on photo_tag_id and secondary indexed on photo_tag columns while storing data in MySql. You can always update based on filter condition of photo_tag_id and photo_tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
photos:
    id,
    who, when, where

tags:   -- this is a many:many mapping table
    photo_id,   -- join to photos.id
    tag VARCHAR(99)
    PRIMARY KEY(tag, photo_id),
    INDEX(photo_id, tag)
```

The column `tag` could have wildlife, nature, adventure, etc

If, by tag, you mean a `category`, and a photo is in only one category, then it would be done differently:  add `category` (or `category_id`) to `photos`.  This is a `1:many` relationship.

Comment: i am not got your point can u please more clear me in this. i just wanna create a table relation in which one column have a multi type tags or keywords and each keyword also has its own table where each entry of main table also reflecct the tag table . as am new please suggest me in more clear way

Comment: "... each keyword also has its own table..." -- Do not have multiple tables.  I am assuming that "tag", "type", and "keyword" are synonyms for each other; if you are thinking of them as somehow different, I missed that.

Comment: thank you for your suggetion  yes also getting these thing same but plz clear me on your suggestion.